# Azure ML problem with installation fastai with conda

Tags: python, conda, fast-ai, azure-machine-learning-service

I am struggling to install the fastbook package for fastai in Azure ML. Below is the error I am getting.

I have created a new environment, and all other fast ai packages are installed.

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed      
                                                                                                                                              
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
Your installed version is: 2.27
```

The command line code is below:

```
 conda install -y pip
 conda install -y ipykernel
 conda install -y -c fastai -c pytorch fastai
 conda install -y -c fastai fastbook
 conda install -y -c fastai nbdev
```

I only get the error for the fastbook package

Comment: Have you tried a fresh env and specifying all requirements from the start `conda env create -n fastai -c fastai -c pytorch pip ipykernel fastai fastbook nbdev`?

Comment: Hi, just tried, and I get this message:
conda-env: error: unrecognized arguments: -c -c pytorch pip ipykernel fastai fastbook nbdev

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, should have been `conda create -n fastai -c fastai -c pytorch pip ipykernel fastai fastbook nbdev`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the installed version of Python was too new for the fastbook package.  When I downgraded to 3.6, it worked.